# Run a locator task

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, address, geocoding

I'm working with ArcGIS javascript api and I have a search function that finds a persons address by name and sorts it into a table inside a modal popup.  It returns multiple people with the same name.  What I want to do is click on one of the addresses and have it take me to that location on the map.

```
function searchResult(data) {
//var arr = [];
var htmlTable = "";
htmlTable = '<table id="tblVoters" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0"  width="90%">';
htmlTable += '  <tr>';
htmlTable += '    <td>Voter Id</td>';
htmlTable += '    <td>Status</td>';
htmlTable += '    <td>Affidavit</td>';
htmlTable += '    <td>Last Name</td>';
htmlTable += '    <td>First Name</td>';
htmlTable += '    <td>Address</td>';
htmlTable += '    <td>City, State, Zip</td>';
htmlTable += '    <td>Drivers License</td>';
htmlTable += '  </tr>';



for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    htmlTable += '<tr><td>' + data[i].voter_id + '</td><td>' + data[i].status + '</td><td>' + data[i].affidavit + '</td><td>' + data[i].name_last + '</td><td>' + data[i].name_first + '</td><td><a href="#" id="locator">' + data[i].address + '</a></td><td>' + data[i].cityStateZip + '</td><td>' + data[i].drivers_license + '</td></tr>';
}

function locate()  {
map.graphics.clear();                   
var locator = new esri.tasks.Locator("url");
var address = {"SingleLine":dojo.byId("locator").value};
locator.outSpatialReference= map.spatialReference;
var options = {
    address:address,
    outFields:["Loc_name"]
}
locator.addressToLocations(address);
```

};

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate whether you are using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript or another "javascript api", please?  Also, be sure to include a snippet of your code that shows where you are stuck.

Comment: I recommend using an MVVM like KnockoutJS. It helps binding complex JSON to your UI and handle events like click. In your case you would bind the Locator results to HTML and display the name. Clicking on the name would give you the target object in a handler function.